# Custom Sorting in Matrix report on particular column

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have created a matrix report. I have a column 'Model' and values are (Classic, semi classic, Grand, twin , full, king , queen). Requirement was to split these values in columns.

I created column group for that and write expression like that:

```
=Switch(Fields!model.Value = "   ", "NULL" ,
    Fields!model.Value = "classic", 1, 
    Fields!model.Value = "semi classic", 1,
    Fields!model.Value = "Grand", 1,
    Fields!model.Value = "Twin", 1,
    Fields!model.Value = "Full", 1,
    Fields!model.Value = "King", 1,
    Fields!model.Value = "Queen", 1
)
```

Now I have to sort these models into particular order ( not in A-Z or Z-A).

order should be :   **twin, Grand, Queen, Classic , Full, semi classic, king**

Can some one help me in this how to twist expression or some property.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got most of this already written. If you set the Sorting to this expression, I think you'll get what you want.

```
=Switch(
 Fields!model.Value = " ", 100 ,
 Fields!model.Value = "classic", 4,
 Fields!model.Value = "semi classic", 6,
 Fields!model.Value = "Grand", 2,
 Fields!model.Value = "Twin", 1,
 Fields!model.Value = "Full", 5,
 Fields!model.Value = "King", 7,
 Fields!model.Value = "Queen", 3)
```

Use the expression above for the Sorting **only**. Don't use this for the values of the cells. For that use your initial values.

By the way, seems like your original switch statement has some redundancy that could be eliminated. This would be different for any values not listed in your switch but other wise would give you the same results:

```
=IIF(Fields!model.Value = " ", "NULL" , 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. if go with your method.

Comment: twin  Grand   Queen    Classic  Full   semiclassic   king
                                                                                                
row 1  :  1                         4     5

row 2  :  1              3          4

row 3  :                                            6           7

Comment: But my requirement is   

           twin  Grand   Queen    Classic  Full   semiclassic   king

row 1  :     1...............................................1.................1

row 2  :    1............................ 1...............         1

row 3  :   .....................................................................................1......................             1

                                                                              As in the end I have to count also for each row.

Is there any method for that you know.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify your requirements. I'm having problems following your comments.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/17aebf41-970e-4630-9ac1-fb810f21ad3a

Comment: i can't edit properly here .sorry.. this link will help u. I am devRitesh